# Using aggregate() function in R for multiple columns

Tags: r, aggregate

I have the following data:

```
dat <- structure(list(Year = c(1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L), Month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), Day = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L), Rainfall = c(1, 35.5, 20.3, 2.5, 32, 66.8, 0, 0, 1.8, 
0, 5.3, 0, 0, 0, 11.7, 40.4, 45.7, 15.3, 21.6, 10.5, 26.2, 54.1, 
1.5, 26.9, 39.4, 21.6, 1.3, 95.6, 10.2, 0, 5.1, 0, 4.1, 2.9, 
0, 0.5, 2.1, 15.7, 14.2, 28.7, 134.2, 26.3, 0, 0, 0, 2.3, 0, 
2.8, 0.3, 0.8, 0, 0, 1.8, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 3.3, 9.1, 31.5, 24.6, 
18.5, 0, 37.1, 111.3, 4.3, 21.1, 3.1, 0, 0, 0, 15.8, 30.7, 6.4, 
68.6, 97.5, 64.3, 47.3, 0, 2.3, 8.7, 53.9, 6.9, 20.9, 94, 7.4, 
0, 1.3, 0, 10.9, 0, 81.8, 10.2, 2.5, 1, 3.1, 12.3, 41.9, 85.9, 
74.4, 13.8, 79.9, 117.7, 16.5, 31.2, 1.3, 1.3, 4.6, 7.1, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 4.8, 2, 3.8, 94.2, 1.8), test = c(1, 35.5, 20.3, 2.5, 32, 
66.8, 0, 0, 1.8, 0, 5.3, 0, 0, 0, 11.7, 40.4, 45.7, 15.3, 21.6, 
10.5, 26.2, 54.1, 1.5, 26.9, 39.4, 21.6, 1.3, 95.6, 10.2, 0, 
5.1, 0, 4.1, 2.9, 0, 0.5, 2.1, 15.7, 14.2, 28.7, 134.2, 26.3, 
0, 0, 0, 2.3, 0, 2.8, 0.3, 0.8, 0, 0, 1.8, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 3.3, 
9.1, 31.5, 24.6, 18.5, 0, 37.1, 111.3, 4.3, 21.1, 3.1, 0, 0, 
0, 15.8, 30.7, 6.4, 68.6, 97.5, 64.3, 47.3, 0, 2.3, 8.7, 53.9, 
6.9, 20.9, 94, 7.4, 0, 1.3, 0, 10.9, 0, 81.8, 10.2, 2.5, 1, 3.1, 
12.3, 41.9, 85.9, 74.4, 13.8, 79.9, 117.7, 16.5, 31.2, 1.3, 1.3, 
4.6, 7.1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4.8, 2, 3.8, 94.2, 1.8)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 
372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 
383L, 384L, 385L, 386L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 
394L, 395L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 
405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 
416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L, 421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is a sample data of daily rainfall from 1979 to 1980. There are four columns: Year, Month, Day, Rainfall, and test.

I want to get the:

```
(1) Mean annual total per column. In this example, the average of the two years. 

So, get the annual total first then get the average across the years. 

I will be applying this for data with 60 columns from 1979 to 2017.
```

I don't know how to do this with aggregate() in R. Im using the following commands but this is only for one column:

```
dat2<-aggregate(Rainfall~Year,dat,FUN=sum,na.rm=T, na.action=NULL)
mean(dat2$Rainfall)

dat3<-aggregate(test~Year,dat,FUN=sum,na.rm=T, na.action=NULL)
mean(dat3$test)
```

Is there an easy way to do this in R? Right now I'm doing it manually per column.

I'll appreciate any help on this!

Comment: You need to calculate mean of rainfall and test for each year, something like this:  dat %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise(Avg_Rainfall = mean(Rainfall), Avg_test = mean(test))

Comment: `aggregate` can take multiple variables at a time on the left hand side - `aggregate(cbind(Rainfall,test) ~ Year, data=dat, FUN=sum)`

Comment: @KarthikS I need to get the sum first then the average. Not the annual mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way using only `aggregate()` and/or `colMeans()`, showing how to select many columns without having to name them:

```
# Sum    
aggregate(dat[4:ncol(dat)], by = list(Year = dat$Year), FUN = sum, na.rm = T, na.action = NULL)
# Mean by year
aggregate(dat[4:ncol(dat)], by = list(Year = dat$Year), FUN = mean, na.rm = T, na.action = NULL)
# Mean without grouping per year
colMeans(dat[4:ncol(dat)])
```

The output:

```
> aggregate(dat[4:ncol(dat)], by = list(Year = dat$Year), FUN = sum, na.rm = T, na.action = NULL)
  Year Rainfall   test
1 1979    833.1  833.1
2 1980   1492.6 1492.6
> aggregate(dat[4:ncol(dat)], by = list(Year = dat$Year), FUN = mean, na.rm = T, na.action = NULL)
  Year Rainfall     test
1 1979 14.12034 14.12034
2 1980 24.87667 24.87667
> colMeans(dat[4:ncol(dat)])
Rainfall     test 
 19.5437  19.5437
```

EDIT: in case they are some non-numeric columns in the mix that should stay as non-numeric, you can replace `dat[4:ncol(dat)]` by `Filter(is.numeric, dat[4:ncol(dat)]`, see an example below:

```
> dat$test <- as.character(dat$test)
> aggregate(Filter(is.numeric, dat[4:ncol(dat)]), by = list(Year = dat$Year), FUN = sum, na.rm = T, na.action = NULL)
  Year Rainfall
1 1979    833.1
2 1980   1492.6
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting the following error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument.  I think the first row (column headers) are included in the sum()? How can I remove this?

Comment: Or maybe is this because of the NA value?

Comment: @Lyndz, with the sample `dat` I was not able to get this error. My guess is that not all your columns are of type numeric, maybe, for ex, your column 45 is of type character.

Comment: See this test: `> dat$test <- as.character(dat$test)
> aggregate(dat[4:ncol(dat)], by = list(Year = dat$Year), FUN = sum, na.rm = T, na.action = NULL)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument`

Comment: here's the link to the data that I'm applying this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/80s37e1s9awopqu/data_station_daily.csv?dl=0

Comment: I read the csv like this `dat<-read.csv("data_station_daily.csv",header=T,sep=",")`

Comment: Your column `MAASIN` is of type character

Comment: OMG! I found it..there's some texts there

Comment: It should be possible to add something to only aggregate and sum with numeric columns, but sometimes it is useful to have these messages because maybe this column is expected to be numeric but the import screwed it up.

Comment: Yes..Thanks! haha.

Comment: But if you replace `dat[4:ncol(dat)]` by `Filter(is.numeric, dat[4:ncol(dat)])` it should work

Comment: I already replaced the characters in that column. Your code is working now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In `aggregate` you can pass multiple variables with `cbind`  and to get the mean use `colMeans` :

```
dat3<-aggregate(cbind(Rainfall, test)~Year,dat,FUN=sum,na.rm=T, na.action=NULL)
colMeans(dat3[-1])
```

However, if there are many columns it is better to get data in long format and then `summarise` them :

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(Rainfall, test)) %>%
  group_by(Year, name) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(sum))
```

Comment: the file has 60 columns...Year Month Day, Rainfall, test.....until the 60th. Thanks for this!

Comment: the one using the dplyr, it doesn't get the annual accumulated first?

Comment: Corrected the `dplyr` method. How can you uniquely identify those 60 columns. In `cols` you can select columns by position, `1:60` or by pattern in their name. `col1`, `col2` etc.

Comment: @Lyndz you can use something like `dat[4:ncol(dat)]` to select all you columns without using explicit names